# With Google Cloud Build, how do I run a Makefile that executes docker and kubectl commands?

Tags: docker, makefile, google-cloud-build, docker-in-docker

I received a project that is built with a number of `Makefile`s which run a number of `docker` commands. I want to build it on Cloud Build.

I know that Cloud Build handles Docker natively, but must work with the existing  Makefile-structure.

I tried the  [*make* Custom Build step](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/make), but Cloud Build failed on lack of `docker` and `kubectl`. So I could add these to the `Dockerfile` of the *make* Custom Build step, but it seems like that is wrong, because then  *make* runs  Docker-in-Docker and this causes problems -- for example, `gcloud` and `kubectl` permissions and   context are missing.

As a  small part of one such a Makefile, here is a target that calls `docker build` and `docker push`.

```
build/myapp/deployer: ...

    docker build \
        --build-arg REGISTRY="$(REGISTRY)/myapp" \
        --tag "$(APP_DEPLOYER_IMAGE)" \
        -f deployer/Dockerfile \
        .

    docker push "$(APP_DEPLOYER_IMAGE)"
    @touch "$@"
```

How do I run these Makefiles in Cloud Build?

Comment: Can you provide a code example of this makefile?

Comment: I added a small sample.

Comment: Ok, your makefile is simply a bash script, isn't it?

Comment: Right, the make just runs some commands, mostly docker build and docker push. However.the make has a complex dependency structure, so I would rather keep it

Comment: And you did achieve a custom builder with Docker Gcloud and kubectl in it?

Comment: Yes. I built such an image, though I'm not sure that's the right way to go. In fact, even the base Cloud Build image has make and docker

Comment: Base Cloud Builder image are made for 1 specific things. You want to build or push with docker use the docker image, want to use gcloud, une gcloud image, same thing with kubectl,... Either you explode your make, or you use it with an "do it all" image.

Comment: The deeper question is how to run docker inside a docker container. This is doable, and in fact the Cloud Build default docker-building image does that, but can be problematic, as in the example I am giving here  of a 'make' process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer to your comment: "How to run docker inside a docker container?", you have to see your custom cloud builder like an runner. You can use it like this in Cloud Build

```
- steps:
  - name: gcr.io/your-project/your-custom-builder
    entrypoint: "bash"
    args: 
      - "-c"
      - |
        Makefile
        <All the script lines that you want which use binaries installed in your custom builder>
```

Here the custom Cloud Builder run the command but the result is stored in your Cloud Build workspace, not in the custom Cloud Builder container.

Comment: Docker-in-docker makes things complicated. For example, docker/kubectl do not come preconfigured with the suitable service user. Further, they run into problems accessing the filesystem.

Comment: guillaume blaquiere: Perhaps this is the better question: How can we use parameters calculated within the Cloud Build process: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59118037/h